# Number picker program is randomly returning "none"

Tags: python

I'm trying to create a program to randomly pick a number in python and not repeat itself. but for some reason, it is returning "none" when I'm guessing a number would be about to repeat. I'm pretty new to python and my code is really messy and insistent so it would be great if someone could help me out here or show a better way of doing it thanks.

```
import random

lastChoice = 0

def choseNewNumber(num1, num2):
    x = random.randint(num1, num2)

    global lastChoice
    if x == lastChoice:
        choseNewNumber(num1, num2)

    else:
        lastChoice = x
        return x

for i in range(1, 50):
    print(choseNewNumber(1, 10))
```

Comment: `return choseNewNumber(num1, num2)` for the first part of the if-clause.

Comment: You only return something if the first try is successful. Use a loop instead of recursion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just have to add `return` in the recursion, The code should be,

```
import random

lastChoice = 0

def choseNewNumber(num1, num2):
    x = random.randint(num1, num2)

    global lastChoice
    if x == lastChoice:
        return choseNewNumber(num1, num2)
    else:
        lastChoice = x
        return x

for i in range(1, 50):
    print(choseNewNumber(1, 10))
```